# Transforming a Github organization into a user

Tags: github

You can [turn a Github user account into an organization](https://help.github.com/articles/converting-a-user-into-an-organization/), but you can't turn an organization into a regular account.

Can I delete a Github organization and register a new account with the same name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Github support staff, 2015-03-18:

> Hi Pierre,
>
> > What if I delete an organization and register a new account? Will I be able to use the same username?
>
> Yes.
>
> Thanks,
> James